# Conditional Formatting for partial duplicates

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Currently I'm using

```
=countif(A:A,A1)>1
```

to highlight exact duplicates in the same columns.

However, I would like to be able to highlight partial duplicates within the column as I tend to annotate the duplicate with another string like '(duplicate)'.

e.g. 
Column A Row 1 apple
Column A Row 2 apple *duplicate

My current formula is unable to highlight the two cells of 'apple' and 'apple *duplicate' as they are not exactly similar.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=AND(A1<>"",
    COUNTIF(
        ARRAYFORMULA(
            REGEXREPLACE(A:A,"\s?\*+duplicate.*","")
        )
        ,REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\s?\*+duplicate.*","")
    )>1
)
```

---

The regular expression:

```
\s?\*+duplicate.*
```

matches

> [space][any number of asterisks]duplicate[anything after]

and removes it. This is to try and make the duplicate values the same.

---

Tested it and it's working for me.

[image: Snipped.]

Comment: Hm no, this highlights the entire column, will you be able to break down your formula some more? 

In addition, there are variants to my duplicate annotation, sometimes I use '***duplicate 2' instead of just '*duplicate', is there a way to just highlight the partial continuous string that is duplicated. 

E.g.

apple *duplicate
apple
apple ***duplicate

is there a formula that would highlight all 3 cells?

Comment: Have made the formula broader. Maybe check out regex101.com to test your values.